# Vertex connection by Yes/No in R Language

Tags: r, networking, plot, dataframe, vertex

What I intend to do with my data frame using the **R** language is to plot it as a network of objects that are connected when someone answers 'YES' to both objects, for example, my data would look similar to:

```
V1     V2  V3  V4 V5  V6  V7 V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22
Fish   Yes Yes Yes  No No Yes  No No  No Yes Yes  No Yes Yes  No  No Yes  No  No  No  No  No
Squid  Yes Yes No  No No Yes  No No  No Yes  No  No Yes  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No
Pigs   No  No  Yes No No  No  No No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No No
```

So in my network, I'd like the vertices to be [Fish, Squid, Pigs] and for a connection to be formed per row, so for example: from the first answer, Fish and Squid would be connected. So it would look something like

Fish - Squid

Fish - Squid

Fish - Pigs

So eventually the data would be the all the objects connected to each other from the sum of all the yes/no answers of the 22 people. I would also want to use the igraph library to plot this data network. I sort of understand how to use igraph so I just really need help with how to create the edge using the yes/no answers. Any advice or help would be appreciated!

*sorry about the vague data table, i'm not sure how to make one on the SO question box.

Comment: Try using `dput` to make a reproducible dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the output from dput() as @Thomas suggested.  This is a great way to share data with folks on stackoverflow, so that they can easily grab it and test code out on it.

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), V2 = c("Yes", "Yes", 
    "No"), V3 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), V4 = c("No", "No", "No"), 
    V5 = c("No", "No", "No"), V6 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), V7 = c("No", 
    "No", "No"), V8 = c("No", "No", "No"), V9 = c("No", "No", 
    "No"), V10 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), V11 = c("Yes", "No", 
    "No"), V12 = c("No", "No", "No"), V13 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"
    ), V14 = c("Yes", "No", "No"), V15 = c("No", "No", "No"), 
    V16 = c("No", "No", "No"), V17 = c("Yes", "No", "No"), V18 = c("No", 
    "No", "No"), V19 = c("No", "No", "No"), V20 = c("No", "No", 
    "No"), V21 = c("No", "No", "No"), V22 = c("No", "No", "No"
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
    "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", 
    "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", "V22"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("Fish", "Squid", "Pigs"))
```

Here's some code to create an edge data frame.

```
# define the vertices
vertices <- row.names(df)
L <- length(vertices)

# set up empty data frame for the edges
numedges <- choose(L, 2)
edges <- data.frame(v1=rep(NA, numedges), v2=NA, numrows=NA)

# cycle through all possible pairs of vertices
# total up the number of people answering "Yes" to both
k <- 0
for(i in 1:(L-1)) {
for(j in (i+1):L) {
    k <- k + 1
    edges$v1[k] <- vertices[i]
    edges$v2[k] <- vertices[j]
    edges$numrows[k] <- sum(df[vertices[i], ]=="Yes" & df[vertices[j], ]=="Yes")
}}
```

This is what the resulting edge data frame looks like:

```
     v1    v2 numrows
1  Fish Squid       5
2  Fish  Pigs       1
3 Squid  Pigs       0
```

Comment: Try this out: `crossprod(t(df == "Yes"))` ;-)

Comment: Wow, @AnandaMahto, that makes short work of things!  If the reshape package is used, the code could be down to just a few lines ... `library(reshape)`  `m <- crossprod(t(df=="Yes"))`  `edges <- melt(m)[melt(upper.tri(m))$value, ]`

Comment: Sticking in base R: `out <- crossprod(t(df == "Yes")); out[upper.tri(out, diag = TRUE)] <- NA; out2 <- data.frame(as.table(out));out2[complete.cases(out2), ]`. But I have no idea what the OP is actually looking for, so I'll refrain from posting an answer. Feel free to integrate it into yours if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I would have also liked to use the crossprod but I kept coming up with errors. But thank you @AnandaMahto I think I'll be doing more work like this in the future so I think I'll be able to use your suggestion by then.